# How to redirect back to the previous page after form submission using its cancel link?

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a form using Drupal 7 Form API. For this I have a cancel link to redirect back to that page from where it comes. This works fine until I do not submit the form: after form submission the cancel link is redirecting me to the same form.

```
<div class="row">
<?php print render($form['name']); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php print render($form['email']); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php print render($form['quantity']); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php print render($form['comments']); ?>
</div>
<div class="btn-area">
<?php print render($form['submit']);?>
<?php print render($form['buttons']);?>
<?php if($form): 
print drupal_render_children($form); 
endif;
$node_url= $_POST['node_url'];
print "<div class='rfq-btn'><a class='btn-close' href='$node_url'>Cancel</a>  </div>";
```

Comment: How do you set `$_POST['node_url']`?

Comment: I have a html form on another page, using POST method to post the value of current url of that node for cancel link

Comment: You could use `<input type="hidden" name="node_url" value="<?php echo $_POST['node_url']; ?>" />`.

Comment: I used it before but after form submission its value also disappears

Comment: Make sure your input field is in the form element.

Comment: `$form['node_url'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => $node_url);` in drupal way.